# Ambiguous reference

Tags: swift, types, casting

I have a simple dot product function:

```
func dotProduct(vectorA: [Float], vectorB: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    return map(zip(vectorA, vectorB), *)
}
```

However, it raises the following error

```
Ambiguous reference to member '*'
```

Any ideas? It seems the type of both vectorA and vectorB are explicitly defined as [Float].

Answer (score 2):

It works if call `map` on the zipped list:

```
func dotProduct(vectorA: [Float], vectorB: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    return zip(vectorA, vectorB).map(*)
}
```

Seems Swift's inference is a bit lacking.

Comment: Ah you beat me to it, I'll remove mine :)

Comment: It's not an issue of Swift's inference being lacking. It's just that `map` is no longer a free function in Swift. It is now defined in an extension of the `SequenceType` protocol, and so you must invoke the `map` method *on* something -- like the sequence returned by zip.

Comment: I assumed that if `map()` was a valid global function, then it would have all the information necessary to translate it to a call on the `SequenceType` that is passed to it.